# Improving the performance of SQL code for querying GraphQL connections

Tags: sql, postgresql, graphql

I'm implementing a GraphQL query resolver for retrieving Connections in my web app according to [this specification](https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm#sec-Pagination-algorithm). I'm using base64 encoded strings of table's unique created_at timestamps to represent opaque cursors. I'm using PostgreSQL as database server.

The SQL code to query posts table with below arguments is:

```
-- first: 20, after: '2020-06-15 14:56:31.456'
-- last: 10, before: '2020-08-09 09:25:49.108'
-- sortBy: title

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM posts
        WHERE title > (SELECT title FROM posts WHERE created_at = '2020-06-15 14:56:31.456')
            AND title < (SELECT title FROM posts WHERE created_at = '2020-08-09 09:25:49.108')
        ORDER BY title
        LIMIT 20
    ) AS forward_pagination_result
    ORDER BY title DESC
    LIMIT 10
) AS backward_pagination_result
ORDER BY title;
```

The problem is that the existence of timestamps corresponding to after or before cursors is unknown. For example querying  by these arguments (after: 'timestamp that doesn't exist', before: 'timestamp that exists'), the result of comparison will be null hence the query results, in spite of the before timestamp being valid. I could separate subqueries from the main query and build my SQL code according to the results of subqueries but that would result multiple calls to database server which is not efficient.

I also tried modifying the above code to include functions like COALESCE:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM posts
        WHERE COALESCE(title > (SELECT title FROM posts WHERE created_at = '2020-06-15 14:56:31.456'), TRUE)
            AND COALESCE(title < (SELECT title FROM posts WHERE created_at = '2020-08-09 09:25:49.108'), TRUE)
        ORDER BY title
        LIMIT 20
    ) AS forward_pagination_result
    ORDER BY title DESC
    LIMIT 10
) AS backward_pagination_result
ORDER BY title;
```

But that runs much slower than the one without COALESCE (120ms vs 5ms for 100k rows).

Can I check for null values and execute query as fast as 5ms or so both at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for the performance difference is that COALESCE function is executed for every row. If I could place it somewhere to run it once the problem would be solved. I don't know a way in standard SQL to conditionally use different WHERE clauses, for that I should probably use procedural languages like PL/pgSLQ. But if I could specify default values for sorting criterion corresponding to after and before cursors I would write:

```
WHERE title > COALESCE((subquery_for_after), 'least_value_for_title')
    AND title < COALESCE((subquery_for_before), 'greatest_value_for_title')
```

Determining least and greatest value for integer and numeric values is easy. Also you can provide far date in past or future for dates. For text values I think empty string would be the least, and for greatest value I use some great unicode number. The complete SQL code will be then:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM posts
        WHERE title > COALESCE((SELECT title FROM posts WHERE created_at = '2020-06-15 14:56:31.456'), '')
            AND title < COALESCE((SELECT title FROM posts WHERE created_at = '2020-08-09 09:25:49.108'), U&'\+10ffff')
        ORDER BY title
        LIMIT 20
    ) AS forward_pagination_result
    ORDER BY title DESC
    LIMIT 10
) AS backward_pagination_result
ORDER BY title;
```

The execution time for the above code is around 6-8ms depending on the existence of after and before cursors.